# Sinon, nested stubbing

Tags: javascript, sinon

I am trying to stub out a module and the return inside of it and having a little trouble. Here is what I have

```
var CrowdControlGet = sinon.stub();
var CrowdControl = sinon.stub().returns({
    get: CrowdControlGet
});
```

this does not seem to work, but when I just have

```
  var CrowdControl = testHelpers.stub()
```

it works fine, how do i get it to return a get inside which is also a stub? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried like this:

```
var CrowdControlGet = sinon.stub();
sinon.stub(CrowdControl, function () {
  return {
    get: CrowdControlGet // or just sinon.stub()
  }
});
```